# using fopen to open file in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have PHP code for downloading file from mysql database.
Im trying to buffer my download into chunk each chunk 1024.
But its look fopen can’t open my file from the database it give error.

```
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/download/get_file_work.php on line 40
```

How to open file in database using fopen function.

My php code

```
<?php
ob_start();
$company = $_GET['company'];
if(isset($_GET['id']))
  {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    if($id <= 0)
      {
        die('The ID is invalid!');
      }
    else
      {
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'sqldata', 'sqldata', 'balhaf');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
          }
        $query = "SELECT mime, name, size, data FROM $company WHERE id = $id";
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);
        if($result)
          {
            if($result->num_rows == 1) {
              $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
              $size = $row['size'];
              $filename = $row['name'];
              $data = $row['data'];
              $mime = $row['mime'];
              if ($fd = fopen ($data, "r")) {
                ini_get('zlib.output_compression');
                ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                while (@ob_end_clean());
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.($filename));
                header('Content-Length:'.($size));
                while(!feof($fd)) {
                  $buffer = fread($fd, 1024);
                  echo $buffer;
                }
              }
              fclose ($fd);
              exit;
            }
            else
              {
                echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
              }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
          }
        else
          {
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
          }
        mysqli_close($dbLink);
      }
  }
else
  {
    echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
  }
?>
```

Comment: wow, can you please format your code so we can actually read it? We're not computers, please consider that you're asking humans for help.

Answer (score 1):

If `$data` is just binary data, you can't use `fopen` on it.  `fopen` only works strings of filenames.  In fact there is no need to read chunks of the data because `$data` apparently already has all of the data.  You can just do:

```
// other headers
header('Content-Length:'.($size));
echo $data;
exit;
```

Comment: but my actually problem if i use as you said when i click on the download link it just show garbage on the screen so i decide to chunk my data, for better salutation. any help regard this ??

Comment: @hadi are you sure that the headers are not already being sent?

Comment: @ Explosion Pills when i use firefox mozilla and google chrome it work fine but not in IE 10.I have debugged the code with some headers utilities to examine the headers request, it appear the headers is not sending back to the user agent (IE browser) it just blank.